# If brine salt percentage is between 1 and 2 percent, can Clostridium botulinum growth prevail over Lactobacillus acidophilus?

Tags: microbiology, bacteriology, fermentation, bacterial-toxins, gut-bacteria

After searching in various websites, I found mostly that *Clostridium botulinum* doesn't grow easily in a salty environment, and that it needs a pH from 4.6 to up;
as I am lactic fermenting some bell peppers, I searched and found that their pH is between 5.5 to 6.5;
I applied a salt concentration of 1 - 2 % on the solution (brine);
I didn't find a clear answer to whether or not the bacteria can grow in those conditions, only that it isn't likely, and most websites make similar statements, therefore looking for clarification
In an environment of about 20 degrees Celsius, salinity of 1-2%, and pH between 5.5 to 6.5 (bell pepper),
is it possible that *Clostridium botulinum* could grow and compete with *Lactobacillus acidophilus*?

Comment: Welcome to Biology.SE. The Biology.SE community has agreed that **questions that show little or no prior research effort** are off-topic on this site. Please [edit] your question and tell us where you've looked for answers, what you *do* know about the topic, and where exactly you still have questions. Under researched questions may be subject to down-voting and closure. Please take the [tour] and consult the [help] starting with [ask] for details. ——— You may find [this webpage](https://food.unl.edu/clostridium-botulinum) helpful.

Comment: Also note that a "colony" is the form seen on growth media — I think what you want to know is do they grow? In addition, there are standards for naming of species (including bacteria). 1) The genus (first part of the binomial) is written out in full (the first time it is used) and is always capitalized. 2) The whole name should be italicized. I have fixed these problems, but please do some reading and revise your question accordingly as soon as possible to avoid receiving downvotes — if your question is closed editing your post will also allow you to request it be reopened.